# Sony SmartWatch - the registration settings are not updated

Tags: android, sony-smartwatch

I have an app that only supports SmartWatch widget (return 1 for getRequiredWidgetApiVersion()) for v1. In v2, I added code to support control and also changed the code to return 1 for getRequiredControlApiVersion().

After v2 installed, I found that I cannot find my app from LiveManager > SmartWatch > Sort applications list.

The problem can be manually fixed by re-installing my app or tapping the "Clear data" for SmartWatch app, but it's not a good solution.

You can easily reproduce the bug by modifying the code of SampleWidgetExtension sample code.

1. install SampleWidgetExtension to phone
2. LiveManager > SmartWatch > Sort application <= no Sample widget, it's correct.
3. change SampleRegistrationInformation.java, return 1 for getRequiredControlApiVersion() and add isDisplaySizeSupported(...) function and return true for it
4. install SampleWidgetExtension to phone
5. LiveManager > SmartWatch > Sort application <= still no Sample widget, it's incorrect.
6. reinstall SampleWidgetExtension
7. LiveManager > SmartWatch > Sort application <= you can see Sample widget from the list

It seems that it's the bug of SmartWatch (v1.2.33) app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Sam, you have indeed identified a bug. However, the bug is not in the SmartWatch application or Liveware Manager, it is in the SDK.

So - we will work hard to fix this as quick as possible and post an update of the SDK on sonymobile.com/developer. When it has been done, I will be sure to update this thread!

Thanks!

**Update**

Fix is now available, downloadable from here: http://developer.sonymobile.com/wportal/devworld/technology/smart-extras/smart-extension-sdk